# Link button's Click Function is not being call

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

I am generating dynamic link buttons in c#.At click of any of them,a other function will be call that will show which link button was clicked.But it is not being call at click of any link button.

This is how i am generating it.

```
 Int32 i; //create a integer variable
 for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) // will generate 10 LinkButton
 {
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton(); //create instance of LinkButton
lb.Text = Convert.ToString(i) + ""; //LinkButton Text
lb.ID = Convert.ToString(i); // LinkButton ID’s
lb.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(i); // LinkButton CommandArgument
lb.CommandName = Convert.ToString(i); // LinkButton CommanName
lb.OnClientClick+= new CommandEventHandler(lb_Command); //Create Handler for it.
//type lb.Command += and press double time Tab Key it will generat the lb_Command() code
 PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lb); // Adding the LinkButton in PlaceHolder
 }
```

This is function code.

```
void  lb_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
Label1.Text = e.CommandName; // will display the which Linkbutton clicked
Label1.Text = "aaaa";
//  Response.Redirect(“LnkBtn.aspx?val=” + Label1.Text); // you can also use as QueryString to send values to another page
}
```

please provide help.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not mentioned anywhere below but make sure you are creating recreating those buttons during the OnInit() phase of every post back ofr your events won't be wired up early enough in the page lifecycle to work anyway.

Comment: i am generating it inside page_load's if (!IsPostBack) event.
Moreover when i click on link button,all the links buttons gets disappears why?

Comment: @user1627138 You're not creating the buttons early enough in the page lifecycle.  They aren't being saved to the view state, so when you post back the server doesn't remember that it had any buttons.  As Eoin has said, you need to add the controls in the `OnInit` event, and you need to do it on every single page load, not just on `!IsPostBack`.

Comment: @OP. I've posted some info in an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong event :

ClientClick is just a client side event triggered in javascript.

What you want is the [Click Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.click.aspx)

[...]

```
lb.Click += new CommandEventHandler(lb_Command); //Create Handler for it.
```

If you still aren't catching the event, then chances are you are declaring your LinkButton dynamically at the wrong time in the Page Lifecycle (as mentionned by Eoin Campbell in his comments and in his answer).

He links to an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx) that's really good on the subject, you should read it to understand why you aren't catching the event.

Judging by your comments on your question and on different answers, you are declaring the button in your Page_Load function. That will not work because Page_Load occurs too late in the page lifecycle.

From what I understand, right now you have :

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
          Int32 i; //create a integer variable
          for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) // will generate 10 LinkButton
          {
              LinkButton lb = new LinkButton(); //create instance of LinkButton
              lb.Text = Convert.ToString(i) + ""; //LinkButton Text
              lb.ID = Convert.ToString(i); // LinkButton ID’s
              lb.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(i); // LinkButton CommandArgument
              lb.CommandName = Convert.ToString(i); // LinkButton CommanName
              lb.OnClientClick+= new CommandEventHandler(lb_Command); //Create Handler for it.
              PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lb); // Adding the LinkButton in PlaceHolder
        }
    }
}
```

You need to get rid of that. Instead, use :

```
void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 i; //create a integer variable
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) // will generate 10 LinkButton
    {
         LinkButton lb = new LinkButton(); //create instance of LinkButton
         lb.Text = Convert.ToString(i) + ""; //LinkButton Text
         lb.ID = Convert.ToString(i); // LinkButton ID’s
         lb.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(i); // LinkButton CommandArgument
         lb.CommandName = Convert.ToString(i); // LinkButton CommanName
         lb.OnClientClick+= new CommandEventHandler(lb_Command); //Create Handler for it.
         PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lb); // Adding the LinkButton in PlaceHolder
    }
}
```

The article linked above will explain why that is. It's a hard concept to grasp but a very important one.

Comment: using onclick gives the error:-
Error 2 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(System.EventArgs)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: The OnClientClick is only part of the problem. Even with OnClick as you stated, his code will only work if he's generating those buttons early enough in the page life cycle.

Comment: well he wasn't getting compile errors in the first place. but he'll continue to get "odd" run time behaviour where clicking on his buttons doesn't "appear" to do anything. And given that he was making the OnClick vs. OnClientClick mistake and misunderstanding the page lifecycle is pretty common when working with dynamic controls... yeah... i think it's worth mentioning.

Comment: The event handler doesn't need to be `protected`.  It can be `private` and it will work just fine.  In fact, it really *should* be private.  The accessibility error is because the name of the event he needs to attach to is `Click`.  That's the public event.  `OnClick` is a protected *method* (not event) that triggers the `Click` event.  Since this class can't access protected members of `LinkButton` he's getting an error.

Comment: @Hugo turns out page Life cycle is an issue for OP. See my response below.

Comment: onclick is not a valid method for linkbuttons.it real method is OnClientClick.
i made a protection level to protected but use OnClientClick but it still didn't give any effect.
:(

Comment: @user1627138 The event handler that you're attacking does not need to be protected, it can and should be private.  The *event* (not method) that you need to attach the event handler to is neither `OnClick` (which isn't an event at all) nor is it `OnClientClick`; you need to attach it to `Click`.

Comment: I just updated my answer with the solution to both initial problems. I think you should be fine with that.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing client and server side code.  OnClientClick is method for attaching client side code.  lb_Command runs on the server side.

Use Click instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx 
versus
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx

Comment: lb.command still didn't work.it didn't get a hit when i click any link button

Answer (score 1):

Ok. two things. as others have pointed out you should be using the `LinkButton` `Command` or `Click` handlers.

But your second problem is that you are running into Page Life Cycle issues by attempting to only generate your controls

1. on if(!Postback)
2. in the `Page_Load`.

Read this: It's a very good article on the subject that dates all the way back to .net 1
https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx

In a nutshell, you should be creating your controls every single time (not just on the initial post) and you need to wire up your event handler (the `+=` part) early enough in the page lifecycle such that the events are wired, by the time the PageLifeCycle attempts to trigger them.

Override the page's `OnInit` method and move your code there, without the `if(!Postback)` check

Comment: The event isn't `OnClick`, it's `Click`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the below code

```
lb.OnClientClick+= new CommandEventHandler(lb_Command); //Create Handler for it.
```

use the following

```
lb.Command+= new CommandEventHandler(lb_Command); //Create Handler for it.
```

Here is the full code. It running at my end.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 i; //create a integer variable 
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) // will generate 10 LinkButton 
        {
            LinkButton lb = new LinkButton(); //create instance of LinkButton 
            lb.Text = Convert.ToString(i) + "&nbsp;"; //LinkButton Text 
            lb.ID = Convert.ToString(i); // LinkButton ID’s 
            lb.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(i); // LinkButton CommandArgument 
            lb.CommandName = Convert.ToString(i); // LinkButton CommanName 
            //lb.Click += lb_Click; //Create Handler for it.
            lb.Command += lb_Command;
            //type lb.Command += and press double time Tab Key it will generat the lb_Command() code 
            form1.Controls.Add(lb); // Adding the LinkButton in PlaceHolder 
        } 

    }

    void lb_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = e.CommandName; // will display the which Linkbutton clicked             
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: lb_command function is not getting still a hit after clicking on the any link button,even all the link button get invisible when i click on any button.
Strange Behaviour.

Comment: @user1627138 That's because you're creating and adding the LinkButtons too late in the page lifecycle.

Comment: i am creating it inside page load.
So whats the solution?

Answer (score -1):

If link button is inheriting from Button class then you should attach to the OnClick event. ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click(v=vs.100)

or

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onclick.aspx

Comment: This isn't windows forms, it's ASP.NET